How to make Firefox render HTML generated on a local server written in Common Lisp?
My goal is something akin to Chapter 12 of Land Of Lisp: using the usocket package in SBCL I want to write a local server that I can connect to with my browser. I started from a helpful example:
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script

(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
(require :usocket)

(defparameter *sock* nil)
(defparameter *sock-listen* nil)
(defparameter *my-stream* nil)

(defun communi ()
  ;; bind socket
  (setf *sock* (usocket:socket-listen "127.0.0.1" 4123))

  ;; listen to incoming connections
  (setf *sock-listen* (usocket:socket-accept *sock* :element-type 'character))

  ; open stream for communication
  (setf *my-stream* (usocket:socket-stream *sock-listen*))

  ;; print message from client
  (format t "~a~%" (read *my-stream*))
  (force-output)

  ;; send answer to client
  (format *my-stream* "<html><body>Server will write something exciting here.</body></html>")
  (force-output *my-stream*))

;; call communication and close socket, no matter what
(unwind-protect (communi)
  (format t "Closing socket connection...~%")
  (usocket:socket-close *sock-listen*)
  (usocket:socket-close *sock*))

When I run this script from the command line (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), I am able to connect to http://127.0.0.1:4123/ with Firefox. However, instead of rendering the HTML, Firefox only displays its source code:
<html><body>Server will write something exciting here.</body></html>

Question: How can I persuade Firefox to render the page instead of displaying the HTML source?
From the answers here and here I assume that I need to set text/html in the HTTP headers. This is corroborated by the curl output
dominik@computer:~$ curl 127.0.0.1:4123 --http0.9 --verbose
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:4123...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 4123 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:4123
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> 
* Closing connection 0
<html><body>Server will write something exciting here.</body></html>

which is markedly different from
dominik@computer:~$ curl example.com -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 256982
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 26 May 2024 18:05:14 GMT
Etag: "3147526947"
Expires: Sun, 02 Jun 2024 18:05:14 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECAcc (dcd/7D7F)
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1256

How can I set the content-type in the usocket package?

Since the server you are implementing is supposed to be a http server, you should supply the response headers then an empty line before the payload. Eg.
(let ((content "<html><body>Server will write something exciting here.</body></html>"))
  (format *my-stream* 
          "HTTP/1.1 200 OK~%~&~
           content-type: text/html~%~&~
           content-length: ~D~%~&~
           ~%~&~
           ~a"
          (length content)
          content))

None of the response headers are required, but as you have experienced they are needed for the browser to handle it as html.

You are my hero, many thanks!
